# Determine if element in one list is smaller than element in another list

Tags: python, list, comparison

I would like to check for particular intervals if there is one corresponding element from another list.

If there is at least one element from the list belonging to the interval, I want to return 1 (no matter how many elements belong to the interval), else 0. The objective is to get a new list full of 0 and 1 (as many as the number of intervals).
I tried to get 2 lists (time and interval) and check if one (or more) element in `time` was smaller than an element in `interval`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
time = [4.84, 9.82, 20.22, 25.66, 28.67, 31.28, 37.08, 43.06, 44.05, 49.24, 62.26, 69.1, 83.52]
newlist=[]

interval = []
for t in range(10, 110, 10):
    interval.append(t)
    
for n, i in enumerate(interval):
    for w, elt in enumerate(time):
        if elt < i and elt > i-10:
            newlist.append(1)
        else:
            newlist.append(0)
newlist
```

I get:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And here is what I would like to get:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: the question actually could be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You get your result because for every interval, you are looping over all time values and appending either a 0 or a 1 for every time value in the time list. However, you just want to append a single 0 or 1 for the complete time list.

Also, your use of `enumerate` in both loops is completely useless since you don't do anything with the indices n and w.

```
time = [4.84, 9.82, 20.22, 25.66, 28.67, 31.28, 37.08, 43.06, 44.05, 49.24, 62.26, 69.1, 83.52]

interval = []
for t in range(10, 110, 10):
    interval.append(t)

new = []
for i in interval:
    if any([val < i and val > i-10 for val in time]):
        new.append(1)
    else:
        new.append(0)
```

To deconstruct that:
You want to append a 1 if **any** value in the list time satisfies your interval condition. That means we have to apply the condition to every item in the time list. Then we have to check if at least one item in the time list is `True`. If there is, then append 1, otherwise append 0.

`[val < i and val > i-10 for val in time]` is a list comprehension that applies the condition to all the values in time and therefore returns a list with boolean values as a result of the condition. For `i = 10`, it looks like this:

```
[True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

The list comprehension is just a short notation for a for loop that creates a list. For example you could rewrite your code that creates the list interval as a list comprehension like this:

```
interval = [t for t in range(10, 110, 10)]
```

The function `any()` returns `True` if any element of the list is `True`, otherwise it returns `False`.